# Trajectory of moving object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, motion-detection, opticalflow

I am working on human motion prediction. I should predict the movement of the human's hand. I use optical flow to detect the motion in a real video and i use (cv2.line) to connect the the previous point (a,b) and the next point (c,d). I need to store this values of variables (a,b,c,d) in a text file (as an extraction of the path of the moving hand). The values are changeable over time. When i use pickle to save the values of variables, it stores just the last values of variables. My question is:

1. Is there a better method to extract the path of a moving object in a real video (githib code or similar)? (optical flow give me so many paths of the moving object and i need just ones to store and then make a prediction)
2. For my current implementation, how can i store all values of the changeable variables (a,b,c,d) for each time step in lines one after another in a text file(not just the last values)?

Thank you

```
# draw the tracks
for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
    a,b = new.ravel()
    c,d = old.ravel()
    mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
    frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    with open("text.txt", 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump([a, b, c, d], f)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about video processing but regarding your second question, you could use CSV format instead of pickle, and append new rows by opening the file in "a" (append) mode rather than "w" (which truncates and overwrites your existing file):

```py
    with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(",".join(map(str, [a, b, c, d])) + "\n")
```

By the way, you don't need to call `f.close()` at the end of the `with` block - it is the `with` block's purpose to close the file (and it will do it even in case an exception is raised).

Also, you might want rearrange the code so that the `for` loop is inside the `with` block, not the other way around. In this way you won't be opening/closing the file with each iteration:

```py
with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
        f.write(",".join(map(str, [a, b, c, d])) + "\n")
```